# StringTokenizer splitting by fullstop even though its not in the delimiters list

Tags: java

I used a `StringTokenizer` like

```
StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), " \\t@");
```

Why does it split by `.` even though its not listed as a delimeter?

My input looks like `1@file1.txt    1`

I want the output to look like `[1, file1.txt, 1]`

Comment: could you give an example of `value`

Comment: also: it's better to use the split method of String rather than StringTokenizer. StringTokenizer has been deprecated for several versions of Java. If there is an issue in there, it'll never be repaired

Comment: @Jiew if you just pass "\\@" as regex (no 't') it'll split just the way you want

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation for StringTokenizer:

> The characters in the `delim` argument are the delimiters
>   for separating tokens. Delimiter characters themselves will not
>   be treated as tokens.

Your tokens are space, backslash, 't' and '@'.

The output from your example is:

```
["1", "file1.", "x", "1"]
```

You can see that the 't' characters in "txt" have been treated as tokens. If you want tab to be a token instead of 't' and backslash, then only use one backslash.

```
StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), " \t@");
```

Which produces:

```
["1", "file.txt", "1"]
```

(i.e. you don't need to double escape "special characters" like you would in a regular expression because they are not special characters, just normal characters.)

Answer (score -2):

I ran following code and it gave expected output.

```
StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer("abc.de", " \\t@");

while(itr.hasMoreTokens()){
    System.out.println(itr.nextToken());
}
```

output:

```
abc.de
```

Is there something like  `'t.'` inside your `value.toString()`? So you may think `'.'` is reason but `'t'`.

Comment: The string to be tokenized in OP's question has a '.' and OP wishes to know why it splits around the '.' eventhough it is not a part of the delimiter.

Comment: @Exception_al it doesn't. yilmaz is right, it's the t's of the .txt extension

Comment: Well that's OP's question ... Not wether his understanding is right or not.

Comment: which is what yilmaz answered in his last sentence

Comment: i am really curious about the reason of negative votes.